# Using the adressed index in an array setter / setter

Tags: c#, arrays, getter-setter

I want to properly handle indexes out of bounds in the getters and setters of an array (not by exception handlers), like this (which does not work):

```
byte[] Board {
    get {
        if (index >= 0 && index < Board.Length)
            return Board[index];
        else
            return 3;
    }
    set {
        if (index >= 0 && index < Board.Length)
            Board[index] = value;
    }
}
```

So that, e.g. `Board[1]` returns the content of Board[1] and `Board[-1]` returns 3.

What would be the correct way to do this?

Comment: You should return `new byte[]{(byte)3}` when the condition isn't met. You can't convert `int` to `byte[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# properties can only get/set "themselves". That means that if you have an array you can only get/set the array itself, not individual values. You can, however, create methods that look and act the way you want like this:

```
public byte getBoardValue(int index) {
  if (index >= 0 && index < Board.Length)
    return _board[index];
  else
    return 3;
}

public void setBoardValue(int index, byte value) {
  if (index >= 0 && index < Board.Length)
        _board[index] = value;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do that with setters and getters.

A workaround is to create an array wrapper class called `Array<T>`. Add a field of type `T[]` as a "backing field". Then implement all the members of `T[]`, like `Length` or maybe the `IEnumerable<T>` interface. For example,

```
class Array<T> {
    T[] _array;

    public int Length => _array.Length;

    public Array(int length) {
        _array = new T[length];
    }
}
```

And here comes the important part, you can now add a indexer to your array wrapper:

```
public T this[int index] {
    get {
        if (index >= 0 && index < _array.Length) {
            return _array[index];
        } else {
            return 3;
        }
    }
    set {
        if (index >= 0 && index < _array.Length) {
            _array[index] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you can use `Array<byte>` as the type of your board.

Comment: I thought I could avoid a wrapper class, but if it is not possible with getters and setters, that should work too. Thank you!

Comment: @InterplanetaryEngineer You could avoid using a wrapper if you use the approach described in user2887596's answer, but as a tradeoff, you get a less concise syntax when you use it. Also, if you think an answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on the checkmark!